# What was freed during a GC?

Tags: java, android, performance, garbage-collection

I'm trying to improve performance of my Android app and I've concluded at least some of the problem lies with excessive garbage-collection. I can use heap tools to see what is getting allocated but it would nice to see what is getting *garbage-collected*.

Is there any way to tell what objects were freed in a Java GC? Is it possible with stock tools? Are there 3rd-party tools for this?

Comment: [PhantomReferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) are used to track if an object is going to be GC. You won't be able to retrieve the actual object that is going to be collected with PhantomReferences therefore you need to keep track of the objects yourself. Moreover, the object is only GC when the PhantomReference is set to null or loses its reference naturally. Maybe [this example](https://github.com/RovoMe/PluginApplication/blob/unstable/PluginFramework/PluginCore/src/main/java/at/rovo/core/injection/InjectionControllerImpl.java) helps

Comment: Out of my brain: You could override the `finalize()` method for the class you are interested in. Add some functionality that logs the fact that the objects gets gc'd. (There probably are some better ways to do this, by using the appropriate profiling tools).

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux `finalize()` bears the danger of reclaiming the object which is going to be GCed and therefore prevent the actual GC of the object. PhantomReferences do not allow this, however if someone keeps the reference to the PR alive, this will also prevent the GC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by capturing "before" and "after" heap dumps, and computing the difference.

The basic problem that makes this hard is that the GC doesn't decide what to *discard*, it decides what to *keep*, so it's not really geared toward gathering lists of freed objects.  In some implementations there might not be per-object discard actions.  (Imagine you have a table with a bit for every page of storage.  At the start of the GC, set all bits to zero.  For every object you keep, set the bit(s) on the page(s) it touches to 1.  When you're done, any page with a zero bit is free and can be used for new allocations.)

You can play some games with finalizers and phantom references for the objects you create, but there's no equivalent for all heap objects.